# How to set different locations to my Google Analytics server-side requests?

Tags: google-analytics, server-side

I'm using an server-side c# client (its not JS, no browser involved) to make some requests on google analytics. So, when I'm constructing the gif hit url with all the information I want to pass to analytics, one of the parameters I'm sending is the utmip, which I suppose google would extract the location informations.

```
string utmGifLocation = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif";
string utmUrl = utmGifLocation + "?" +
    "utmwv=" + Version +        
    "&utmhn=" + domainName +
    "&utmr=" + documentReferer +
    "&utmp=" + documentPath +
    "&utmac=" + account +
    "&utmip=" + remoteIP + ...
    ...
```

That's my problem: whatever ip I'm using to make the requests, google it's mapping all the requests to the same place, which is here, where I'm sending the requests. So, is that utmip parameter still working? Does anybody have any idea how to set manually different locations to my requests?

Answer (score 2):

> > Change the prefix on your Analytics web property ID from UA- to MO- in the server-side snippets given below. For example, if your web property ID is UA-12345-67, you would use MO-12345-67 in your server-side snippets.

And, set the IP address as so the fourth octect is 0 (zero) so 124.455.3.123 becomes 124.455.3.0

`utmip` is available for mobile requests of the tracking gif. It is only available if you prefix your web property ID with `MO`.

Comment: Yea man, tried that way already, but it's not working.. So I thought that could have changed.. tnx man, will try little bit more ;)

Comment: @brunosm Can't think of what else it could be. If you find a solution, please post.

Comment: I got it. It's actually working on the normal reports. The problem was because I was using the GA Real Time (BETA), and there, it's not mapping properly :P

Comment: @brunosm Glad to hear you got it worked out. Thanks for posting back.